# how do i fully customize a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i want to customize my tableview, like the tipulator app for the iphone. 
[image]

And heres my app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the others are right in suggesting ways to subclass `UITableView` or its components, this screenshot doesn't look like it's showing a `UITableView`.

My guess is that they're just drawing custom images onto a background and checking certain areas for taps. What you should do is read up on the drawing methods as well as on intercepting taps and touches.

Comment: It could be a UITableView added as a subview with a custom frame.

Comment: how can i do this? Alexsander

Comment: You have two options: a) look at the `UIView` drawing methods or b) create `UIButton`s with custom images (that you can make in Photoshop).

Answer (score 4):

Each [UITableViewCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a few subviews which you can replace with your own. They are:

- [UITableViewCell.imageView](http://file:///Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_1.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW45)
- [UITableViewCell.contentView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW18)
- [UITableViewCell.backgroundView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW5)
- [UITableViewCell.accessoryView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006938-CH3-SW14)

As Gendolkari pointed out, [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com) has a great [guide on custom UITableViews](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

The theory is that you replace each of those views with an appropriate view to "skin" your UITableViewCells.

When replacing the background view, you check for the first and last cells when skinning the background view, otherwise you can use a "middle" background image. Implement it as a UIImageView. As far as the other views, use what you want.

Additionally, you can use a completely custom NIB file and load that in instead of the default styles provided by UIKit.

Comment: +1 because it's more detailed than my response. Though I'd also point out that the contentView property is readonly, and you cannot replace it with your own View. You can only add your own subViews to it.

Comment: Gendolkari - Are you sure about not being able to subclass the contentView? Even so, you can still customize it by adding subviews, as you said.

Comment: Yup, just double-checked. Documentation and compiler confirm; contentView is a readonly property.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really good guide on custom styling for your table:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: Um, I don´t think I have explained my problem fully. I will post an image of my app and tell you exactly what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own UITableViewCell, and use it, rather than a "generic" one.

You can do this directly in XCode with "File->New File" Then in "Cocoa Touch Class", choose "Objective-C Class" - and under the "Subclass" popup, select "UITableViewCell".

It well generate a XIB, which you can use in IB to customize the look.

Instantiate and pass-in *there* cells in your UITableView code, instead of the normal UITableViewCells.

Comment: There is no reason to do this. It adds extra XIB file for no reason. The only benefit is that you isolate your cell code.